# Windows Common Item Dialog: ctypes + COM access violation

Tags: python, windows, com, ctypes, access-violation

I am trying to use the `ctypes` module to make calls to Windows' [Common Item Dialog API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The code shown below is roughly based on the steps outlined in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Its only dependency is the `comtypes.GUID` module.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import byref, POINTER, c_int, c_long
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, HRESULT
from comtypes import GUID

CLSID_FileOpenDialog = '{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}'
IID_IFileDialog = '{42F85136-DB7E-439C-85F1-E4075D135FC8}'
#IID_IFileOpenDialog = '{D57C7288-D4AD-4768-BE02-9D969532D960}'
CLSCTX_SERVER = 5
COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED = 2
FOS_PICKFOLDERS = 32
FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM = 64

ole32 = ctypes.windll.ole32
CoCreateInstance = ole32.CoCreateInstance
CoInitializeEx = ole32.CoInitializeEx

CoInitializeEx(None, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)

ptr = c_int()
error = CoCreateInstance(
    byref(GUID(CLSID_FileOpenDialog)), None, CLSCTX_SERVER,
    byref(GUID(IID_IFileDialog)), byref(ptr))
assert error == 0

ptr = ptr.value
c_long_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
print('Pointer to COM object: %s' % ptr)
vtable = ctypes.cast(ptr, c_long_p).contents.value
print('Pointer to vtable: %s' % vtable)

func_proto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(HRESULT, HWND)

# Calculating function pointer offset: 3rd entry in vtable; 32-bit => 4 bytes
show_p = ctypes.cast(vtable + 3*4, c_long_p).contents.value
print('Pointer to show(): %s' % show_p)
show = func_proto(show_p)
show(0)
```

Everything works as intended until the first call to `show(0)`:

```
 WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xXXXXXXXX
```

(Output may vary.) For comparison, I have carried out the same steps in AutoHotkey_L, which has direct access to COM.

```
CLSID := "{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}"
IID := "{42F85136-DB7E-439C-85F1-E4075D135FC8}"

ptr := ComObjCreate(CLSID, IID)
vtable := NumGet(ptr + 0, 0, "Ptr")
    show := NumGet(vtbl + 0, 3 * A_PtrSize, "Ptr")

MsgBox ptr: %ptr% vtable: %vtable% show: %A_PtrSize%

DllCall(show, "Ptr", ptr, "Ptr", 44)
```

The resulting macro pops up an Open File dialog, as expected. The vtable pointer offsets are the same in both cases, but only the Python version throws up an access violation.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

[I apologize for not adding more hyperlinks where appropriate, but as a new user I am limited to two at a time.]

**Background**:
I am putting together a lightweight module which provides a native save/open file dialog for use in Python scripts. So far I have been unable to find an implementation in pure Python. Those that exist rely on UI toolkits such as Tkinter or wxPython.

Comment: Have you tried `win32com` instead?

Comment: No, I haven't. It's part of the pywin32 package, isn't it? I would like to keep dependencies to a bare minimum, and pywin32 is something of a heavyweight in that regard.

Comment: OK, good to know. It's probably worth noting that the code looks rather fragile since it relies on these vtable offsets -- are you sure you are running 32-bit Python? Maybe show what the `print` statements are producing.

Comment: Positive. I agree about the vtable offsets; I understand that `comtypes` has a more robust interface mechanism. I have yet to figure out how it works, though. Unfortunately I can't post it inline, but here's a screenshot of the python console and AHK output: http://i.imgur.com/dQhTZ.jpg

Comment: Random thing to try: does it work if you run the script with `pythonw`?

Comment: If you want to access the full functionality of IFileDialog, you probably have to reimplement half of comtypes yourself.

Why don't you use ctypes to access the common file open/save dialog from windows?  This would be MUCH easier.

Comment: @nneonneo: no, it didn't -- theller's answer explains why.

Comment: @theller: apparently those are superseded by the Common Item Dialog API, starting with Vista. I am uncertain of the exact differences between the two. [MSDN documentation of Open and Save As Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960(v=vs.85).aspx) (I assume you mean this).

Comment: I am a bit lost here. Could you perhaps [advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes) as to how to use [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) with ctypes? I'm trying to copy using the standard new Windows way and a bit jammed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

COM methods take an additional parameter: The 'this' pointer.  It is implicit when you call the method from C++, in C (and in ctypes) you must supply it yourself.

Change the line

```
func_proto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(HRESULT, HWND)
```

into

```
func_proto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(HRESULT, c_long, HWND)
```

and this line

```
show(0)
```

into

```
show(ptr, 0)
```

and your code will work.

Comment: Perfect, that solved the issue. I was unaware of this implicit pointer -- I'll keep it in mind in the future. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to experiment:  There is a call_commethod() function in the _ctypes module which would make your code more simple.

Comment: If you want to experiment:  There is an undocument call_commethod() function in the _ctypes module which would make your code much more simple.

I don't have time to try it out; the only very old sample code that you can look at is here (this code is older than comtypes):
http://ctypes.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ctypes/ctypes/samples/Windows/COM.py?hideattic=0&revision=1.6&view=markup

You call it with the pointer to the COM object, the index of the com method in the vtable (3 in your case), and the argument tuple. Optionally you supply a tuple containing the argument types.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helps me here: [SetValue and Release are not functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579742/setvalue-and-release-are-not-functions)